# Sending email using Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have my outlook configured with my office id and am extremely new to batch scripting. What is the simplest way (simplest code) to send an email via batch file to my colleague.

thanks

Comment: If you can use external tools check blat -> http://www.blat.net/examples/batch.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see 3 options for you:

1. The bottom line is there's no built-in way in batch, but there are third-party tools like blat etc. that can be called from a batch file.
2. You can enable the installed SMTP Server of Windows. And then run a Powershell script:

   ```
   $smtpServer = "system.abc.com"
   $smtpFrom = "dontreply@abc.com"
   $smtpTo = "something@abc.com"
   $messageSubject = "Put your subject here"

   $message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto
   $message.Subject = $messageSubject
   $message.IsBodyHTML = $true
   $message.Body = Get-Content debug.txt

   $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
   $smtp.Send($message)
   ```
3. You can enable the installed SMTP Server of Windows. And then run a VBScript:

   ```
   Const ForReading = 1
   Const ForWriting = 2
   Const ForAppending = 8
   Const FileToBeUsed = "debug.txt"
   Dim objCDO1
   Dim fso, f
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(FileToBeUsed, ForReading)
   Set objCDO1 = CreateObject("CDO.Message")
   objCDO1.Textbody = f.ReadAll
   f.Close
   objCDO1.TO ="something@abc.com"
   objCDO1.From = "dontreply@abc.com"
   objCDO1.Subject = "Put your subject here"
   objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration /sendusing") = 2 
   objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration /smtpserver") = "system.abc.com"
   objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Item("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration /smtpserverport") = 25 
   objCDO1.Configuration.Fields.Update     
   objCDO1.Send
   Set f = Nothing
   Set fso = Nothing
   ```

Choice is yours.